# Sample Rails apps with rspec coverage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I need to see examples of rspec used in a live Rails project. Please suggest some open source Rails apps which has good rspec coverage and can can act as a good example to study Rspec.

Regards,
Pankaj

Comment: You would have to specify many other details about what you want to use for writing specs. What other frameworks you want to use for mocking and stubbing, any factories for sample data etc. You could just browse through github to check for some basic specs if you want. I dont think any live project's spec examples would help you if your project aims for a purpose different than the project whose specs you are looking at.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same need and I have started studying https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora. It is a high profile Rails app and has extensive RSpec coverage but I can't tell if they excercise best practices.
Another rspec suite I'm studying is from https://github.com/resolve/refinerycms